# Visual Studio 2017 (TE) - FileNotFoundException:Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common

Tags: visual-studio-2017

The following FileNotFoundException was thrown by opening "STEPS" and "ASSOCIATED AUTOMATION" tabs of a "Test Case" work item type in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Test Edition:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.AssociatedAutomationControl.get_TestManagementService()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.AssociatedAutomationControl.get_TestCase()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.AssociatedAutomationControl.RelayoutControls()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls.AssociatedAutomationControl.InvalidateDatasource()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.LegacyWorkItemControl.InvalidateDatasource()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WorkItemControl.ControlFactory_ControlCreated(Object
>   sender, ControlCreatedEventArgs e)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfControlFactory.OnControlCreated(ControlCreatedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfControlFactory.CreateControl(String
>   fieldName, String preferredControlType, String fallbackControlType,
>   StringDictionary properties)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfFormRenderer.CreateControl(FormElement
>   element)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WpfControls.WpfFormRenderer.RenderCollection(Grid
>   panel, FormElementCollection collection, Int32& currentCol)

The user has the rights the view the content on web interface.
The behavior is not reproducable with other versions of Visual Studio 2017 (Premium, Enterprise etc.)
I tryed to workaround the issue by copying the missing dll (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll) from a Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installation of a diffrent machine to following folders of the Test Edition installation, but not helped:

- Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
- Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\TestHost
- Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
- Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

Please let me know, how can be this issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able the workaround the issue.

Setting the registry value "EnableLog" DWORD to 1 under
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Fusion
provided more details about the problem in the fusion log, in particular the path of the assembly (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer):

> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio/2017/TeamExplorer/Common7/IDE/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Controls,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

In ActivityLog.xml were several download attempts logged for Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.DLL
I took the first one (which was the same as in Fusion Log):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\TeamExplorer\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team
>   Explorer

and copyed following three missing dlls there:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Resource.dll
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Vsip.dll

After a Visual Studio restart all content of the test case work item was loadad correctly.